# How to display the output of the following code using iterators?

Tags: c++, vector, graph, stl

This code is for creating adjacency list(i think) and i want to display the content in the vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
int main() {
    int N, M;
    fscanf( stdin, "%d%d", &N, &M );
    vector< int > graph[ N + 1 ];
    int i, u, v;
    for ( i = 0; i < M; ++i ) {
        fscanf( stdin, "%d%d", &u, &v );
        graph[ u ].push_back( v );
    }
    /*vector<int>iterator::it;
    for(it=graph.begin();it!=graph.end();it++)
    cout<<*it<<endl;*/
}
```

I tried to display the output using the lines commented in the code but it gives me compile error saying:

```
struct std::iterator used without template parameters
```

Your help will be appreciated....

Comment: `vector<int>iterator::it;` ==> `vector<int>::iterator it;` and `it=graph.begin();it!=graph.end();it++` ==> `it=graph[WhatEverIndexYouWantToShow].begin();it!=graph[WhatEverIndexYouWantToShow].end();it++`

Answer (score 0):

You can use index instead of iterators in C++ vectors.

```
for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    cout<<graph[i]<<endl;
```

In order to use iterator you have to correct your code such as following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N, M;
    fscanf( stdin, "%d%d", &N, &M );
    vector<int> graph;
    int i, u, v;
    for ( i = 0; i < M; ++i ) {
        fscanf( stdin, "%d%d", &u, &v );
        graph.push_back(u);
        graph.push_back(v);
    }
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    for(it=graph.begin();it!=graph.end();it++)
    cout<<*it<<endl;
}
```

you problem is creating array of vector in your instantiation.

Comment: Is my code successfully creating an adjacency list?

Comment: no, because every input is being placed in a different vector in your vector array

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
int main() {
    int N, M;
    fscanf( stdin, "%d%d", &N, &M );
    std::vector< int > graph[ N + 1 ]; //try to use std::vector<std::vector<int>> - c kind array should have fixed (compilation time) size
    int i, u, v;
    for ( i = 0; i < M; ++i ) {
        fscanf( stdin, "%d%d", &u, &v );
        graph[ u ].push_back( v );
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i <= N; ++i){
        std::cout << i << ": ";
        for ( std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = graph[i].begin(); it != graph[i].end(); ++it){
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
    }
}
//try to use some compilation flag:
//-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wfloat-equa
```